# Difficulties in storing referring site name and ip address

Tags: php, curl, joomla3.0, http-referer

My scenario is this : 1st site sends a request with various parameters as query strings by php curl to 2nd site. 2nd site class method handles the request with various comparisons on the incoming parameters and stores some data in table along with referring site(1st site) name and IP address by this way -

```
$url = parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
$ref_site = $url['host'];
$ref_site_ip = gethostbyname($ref_site);
```

But it's not working in my production server when i was testing it, there is no value for $ref_site and $ref_site_ip variables meaning $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] is not working for many reasons, may be for 1st site's curl request....

does following works properly ?

```
$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $_SERVER['REMOTE_HOST']
```

It's look like by $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] i saw a IP address which i did not verify fully for whether it's referring site(1st site) ip or 2nd site ip, i will update about it soon if possible.

Now what other ways i can get referring site name and IP certainly ?

FYI I will have no control on 1st site codes because those sites will be of various users and those site codes used curl to send request which i definitely know coz those are my known cms site.

Comment: I didn't quite catch what you need ..but i think the first site should send the `$_SERVER['http_referer']` to the second one so you can get th

Comment: well i described well and may be 1st site not sending the $_SERVER['http_referer'] with curl request so is it's empty. Now are there no ways to get at least a referrer IP ?

Comment: maybe using php-fpm for development (where it's called `$_SERVER['http_referer']`), and using apache mod_php on the prod server (where it'd be called `apache_request_headers()['http_referer']` )

Comment: No same result, that remote_addr showed a ip address which i tried to convert as site name but failed all the ways. So :(

Comment: No ways to catch referer site name and ip when http_referer server variable not working?

Answer (score 0):

You can use IP protection later in `.htaccess` like this.

This will block all files in folder `cron`

```
<FilesMatch "cron\.php$">
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 10.0.0.0/24
</FilesMatch>
```

This will only block files with name `cron.php`

```
<Files "cron.php">
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 10.0.0.0/24
</Files>
```

Now to your security. The best way would be to create hash for every query. For instance in the file that send request.

```
$time = time();
$secret = 'MySecretWord';
// Your IP address that will be detected in $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] on accepting server
$ip = '10.10.10.10'; 
$hash = md5($time.$ip.$secret);
```

Now you include this `$hash` and `$time` into GET request. And on accepting site

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
$time = $_GET['time'];
$secret = 'MySecretWord';
$hash = md5($time.$ip.$secret);

if($hash != $_GET['hash'])
{
    echo "Back off a*hole!";
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Hi there thanks for answering, can u put some details in your answer regarding my question as i am not getting fully. I want to get referring site name and IP when $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] value is empty ?.

Comment: Let's say you want to protect and be sure you process only queries from particular server. And you should not use referrer. This is most easy header to fake.

Comment: did you mean put some code in first site from where request coming to 2nd site? As i said it's not possible coz first site is a cms site where i can't code.

Comment: Then edit your topic and show full request it sends. All the parameters it includes and all the headers. Then we can think something out.

Comment: I will try as i hinted that in 1st site in curl request there was no header for http referrer set so in 2nd site it's not being caught

Comment: Just use something like `error_log(print_r($_REQUEST, TRUE), 3, JPATH_ROOT.'/tmp/log.txt')` and same for `print_r(http_get_request_headers())` then go to `./tmp/log.txt` and see what you get after request is sent.